# Image inside of a check box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just wondering can you put a image inside the check box to make it more colorful?
I have searched a lot about this, but didn't find anything that could help me

Edit: I have done so when the check box is "checked" a menu pops up.
HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet href="css.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/icon"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT4??4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $(".box a").on("click",function() {
        $("#toggle-nav").prop('checked', false)
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<!-- start header -->
<header id="head">
  <div class="something">
      <nav id="menu">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-nav"/>
        <label id="toggle-nav-label" for="toggle-nav"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></label>
        <div class="box">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#play"><i class="icon-home"></i> Play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-copy"></i> XXXXXX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
  </div>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: show your code please

Comment: please add your code first

Comment: please add code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Background image css property.

Deom: http://jsfiddle.net/kEHGN/1/

```
    input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    background-image: url('img1.png');
    height: 16px;
    width: 17px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
   background-image: url( background-image: url('img2.png');
   height: 16px;
   width: 17px;
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   }
```